# Perl6 REPL print behaviour

Tags: variable-assignment, read-eval-print-loop, raku

When I execute the following statement in the Perl6 REPL:

```
my $var = 1, 2, 3;
```

it prints:

```
(1 2 3)
```

This seems curious to me, because `$var` is actually assigned a single integer (i.e. `$var.WHAT` returns `(Int)`), rather than a `List` of `Int`s.

I take it that the reason that an `Int` is assigned is the higher precedence of the item assignment operator (`=`) relative to the comma operator (`,`), which leaves the `,2,3` in sink context. But why does the REPL display a `List` of `Int`s? And what does the REPL in general display after the execution of a statement?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The REPL basically does a `say (my $var = 1,2,3)`.  Because the result of that expression **is** a `List`, it will show as `(1 2 3)`.  Inside that expression, only the first element of that list gets assigned to `$a`, hence it being an `Int`.

So why didn't it warn about that?  This does, as you pointed out:

```
$ perl6 -e 'my $a = 1,2,3'
WARNINGS for -e:
Useless use of constant integer 2 in sink context (lines 1, 1)
Useless use of constant integer 3 in sink context (lines 1, 1)
```

whereas this doesn't:

```
$ perl6 -e 'say (my $a = 1,2,3)'
(1 2 3)
```

The reason is simple: because of the `say`, the `,2,3` are no longer in sink context, as they *are* being used by the `say`.

Comment: Very nice; something that seemed off suddenly makes complete sense :-)

Comment: It's why `perl6 -e` can often be better than the REPL for testing stuff.